# Problem with async functions with Firebase Storage and Firestore on Ionic3

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the downloadURL from an image I have uploaded.
With this function I upload the image to Firebase Storage

```
uploadImage() {
  this.image = 'movie-' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
  let storageRef: any,
  parseUpload: any;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('imgs/' + this.image);
  parseUpload = storageRef.putString(this.cameraImage, 'data_url');     
})
```

The thing is that I want to save the image URL so I can take it from a document on Firestore.
In order to do so I have this function to get the dowloadURL once the image is uploaded.

If I am not wrong this method should return an string, correct me If I am wrong, because If it isn't I would not be able to save it on Firestore

```
async getImgFromServer(imgName: string) {
  let img;
  let downloadIMG;
  img = firebase.storage().ref("/imgs/" + imgName).getDownloadURL();
  let ref= firebase.storage().ref();
  const imgRef = ref.child("/imgs/" + imgName);
  const downloadURL = await imgRef.getDownloadURL()
  return downloadURL
}
```

The only problem is that in order to do so, the image must be uploaded.
I know this function will always return the url if the image is uploaded.
The thing is that I dont know how to make this function work when the **uploadImage()** is complete.
After getting the the url this is my function to save the url on the Firestore Cloud database.

```
 updateImgFromServer(image,id){
  this.firestore.doc(`public/${id}`).set({
    img:image,
  });
 }
```

Is there a way to ensure that the second function(**getImgFromServer()**) will be execute only after the first one(**uploadImage()**) has finished?

I know that there are ways to get the downloadURL once the file is uploaded on the first snippet I put. If anyone knows how to make it work It would fine too.

Answer (score 1):

[putString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putString) is asynchronous and returns an [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) that tracks the progress of the upload, which you need to use.  It has a [then()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method which works just like a promise, so use that to determine when the upload is complete.

Comment: I have followed the UploadTask doc and also this [one] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=es-419).
However when I try to upload it, I am getting and error that says:  `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined`.
This is my code at the moment, i will upload a [image](https://i.imgur.com/T8HKBVV.png) as the code won't fit here.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem that the one you originally asked. Please ask a separate question with your details

Comment: Done, thanks im kinda new to StackOverflow and don't really know the limits of when to create a new question or not. Here it is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611656/problem-with-the-uploadtask-from-putstring) in case you could help me. Thanks