# Problem with the UploadTask from putString()

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am having problems with the UploadTask from Firebase Storage.
I am trying to upload an image and then saving the image URL on Firestore Cloud. To do so I have this code:

```
newuploadImage() {
    this.image = 'movie-' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
    let storageRef: any,
    parseUpload: any;
    storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('imgs/' + this.image);
    parseUpload = storageRef.putString(this.cameraImage, 'data_url')
    parseUpload.on('state_changed',
    function (snapshot) {
    }, function (error) {
    }, function () {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        parseUpload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
            const idPubli = this.firestore.createId();
            const idReto = this.firestore.createId();
            let IDUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            let img = downloadURL
            const idPuntPubli = this.firestore.createId();
            let participacionCreadora = true;
            let punt = 0;
            this.firestore.doc(`public/${idPubli}`).set({
                idPubli,
                idReto,
                IDUser,
                img,
                idPuntPubli,
                participacionCreadora,
                punt,
            })
        });
    })
}
```

The image is uploaded fine, however when It tries to execute the **this.firestore**, the console log is giving me this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined

I dont know how to get over that error.

EDIT

This is the import and the constructor in case there is something wrong.

```
import {  AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

constructor(public camera: Camera, public firestore: AngularFirestore) {
  }
```

Comment: can you share your constructor ? let me know where you are initializing firestore ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the import and constructor. As far as I know it should be correct as I have done the same on other files and it has always worked.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely hit a scope issue, which you can resolve by replacing this function:

```
.then(function (downloadURL)
```

With an arrow-function (which preserves the lexical scope).

```
.then((downloadURL) =>
```

Comment: Now instead of getting problems the firestore, im getting problems on any firestore function. This is the error now:

 **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createId' of undefined**

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.firestore`? It's not in your sample. Maybe you haven't initialized it?

Comment: I have editted the question and now it has the constructor and the import lines.
I have been able to use the database all the time with just that, until now.

Comment: @FernandoSanchezdeNieva - you have nested `function...` that can all be converted to arrow functions. i.e. `function (snapshot)`, `function (error)` and `function()` should all be changed to preserve your scope.

Comment: I dont really understant what you want me to do?
You want me to change all the `,function(snapshot){
},function(error){ }, function () {` to: `parseUpload.on('state_changed', (snapshot) =>{})`

Comment: @FernandoSanchezdeNieva - that's the idea. Background reading on arrow functions and alternatives here: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/04/typescript-scope-responsibility/

Comment: It works however everytime the snapshot changes it creates a doc on the Firestore Cloud, is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my code, may be it will be helpful for you.

```
  this.imageFile.name.substr(this.imageFile.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(this.filePath);
  this.task = this.storage.upload(this.filePath, this.imageFile);
  this.uploadPercent = this.task.percentageChanges();
  this.task
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
          this.imageUrl = url;
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
  return this.uploadPercent;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation how this code may help?